# XSLT2 Convert String to Date

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT 2.0 i have a string in my source xml that looks like this `02/23/1981` I'd like to find an XSLT function that will convert this to an actual date `1981-02-23`

basically, the opposite of how format-date will take a date and return a string with the format picture specified.

Does something like this even exist? Every example i can find around StackOverflow, or on the internet as a whole describe formatting a date as a string which is cool and all, but i have a string with a known format, and it needs to land in a field that is a Date.

Thanks for the advice.

i'm aware of this nifty `format-date` function in xslt 2.0 which seems to only be capable of converting a date into some string version of that date.

Comment: Use some XSLT-'substring' code from SO and adjust the order.